# Changing constant global variable

Tags: c, constants

There is a constant global variable defined in another module.

I would like to manipulate this variable during run time (as I can't change in the other module and remove the const keyword).

I know that constants are put in ROM ...

The code will be downloaded to a micro controller (leopard powerpc 5643) , so I think that constants will be in the Flash Memory (not the normal PC ROM)

I have tried something like this and the compiler produced an error during compilation:

```
const int global_Variable = 0;
const int* ptr = &global_Variable;
*ptr = 5;
```

So , do you know any other way to accomplish this ?

Comment: Constants in ROM cannot be manipulated. If you could give us more details about the platforms you are compiling to, I might be able to tell you some tricks.

Comment: You can smth like this `int local_variable = global_variable; local_variable ++;`

Comment: @MikeMinaev This will not work as `local_variable` does  not refer to the same storage as `global_variable`.

Comment: @FUZxxl oh i see, http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter8/const_and_volatile.html

Comment: Depends where `global_var` is used. If you compile all code that uses it yourself (but don't want to change it for some reason) you can just say something like `#define global_variable my_var` and assign `my_var` any value you like. The code which supposedly uses `global_variable` is then really using `my_var`, with the value you choose. Of course that value wouldn't be persistent the way `global_var`'s is, without further effort.

Comment: Ramy, you might want to tell us what problem led you to this question. Perhaps there is a solution to your original problem that does not involve changing constants?

Comment: Do you really need to change the variable at run-time (i.e. regard it as *variable*) or rather do you simply want to change the value of of the constant?  If the latter, you can use information from the map file to patch the binary/hex file after the build.  If the former, then you really can't and should not want to!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know that the constant really is put into ROM (or, more likely, flash) on your platform, then of course you won't be able to modify it, at least not directly.

If it's flash, you *might*, but you're going to have to dive a bit deeper since reprogramming flash memory is *not* done by just writing to it, you must erase the relevant portion and there are often block/sector size limitations to deal with. It won't be pretty.

Your actual code fails to compile since you can't write through a `const` pointer (that's the point of the `const`, after all). You can cast away that and force the compiler to generate the write, but of course it won't *work* if the target address points to non-writable memory:

```
const int global_Variable = 0;
int *ptr = (int *) &global_Variable; /* Cast away the const. */
*ptr = 5; /* Do the write! */
```

Again, this *won't work* if `global_Variable` is in non-writable memory. You will get undefined results.

Lastly, which is so obvious that I didn't even think to write it: what you're doing sounds lika a very bad idea. Obviously the software you're working on was designed with the assumption that `global_Variable` be *constant*. You're trying to overthrow that particular part of the design, which very likely will break lots of things if you succeed. In other words: consider not doing this.

Comment: The code will be downloaded to a micro controller (leopard powerpc 5643) , so I think that constants will be in the Flash Memory (not the normal PC ROM)

Comment: Thanks for this advice :)
Actually the code compiles now after your modification, but an exception is thrown when I try to run the code.

Comment: @RamySameh That's your undefined results right there, then. :) You can't change non-writable memory by trying to write to it.

Comment: Well, the owner of this module left the company, and the new requirements forces me to do so :D
I think you know this kind of problems ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you manage to place `global_variable` in a memory region that is writeable, here is a way to change its value. Notice that this won't work if `global_variable` is not physically writeable, e.g. because it sits in the ROM area.

```
int *ptr = (int*)&global_variable; /* the compiler will warn you about this */
*ptr = 5;
```

Notice that you might run into other problems down the road as the compiler might assume that the content of a variable declared as `const` does not change during the runtime of the program. You violate this assertion by altering the variable's value, so expect strange results.

Comment: you could modify the linker.cmd file so it 'copies' the variable from flash to ram, (all references will point to the ram location) then use the runtime relocation table to actually copy the variable to the ram location.  This does mean you need to know what you are doing with the linker .cmd file and need to add a bit of code to either startup or main() to actually copy the variable